# How to get exported values (MEF) in metro style apps

Tags: mef, windows-runtime

I recognized, that MEF is limited for metro style apps. There is no container anymore, so how can I get specific exported values like `ILogger logger = container.GetExportedValues<ILogger>();`?
Is the any tutorial available covering the metro version of MEF?

Thanks for Help,
Eny

Comment: have you found a solution? I've ended up with the ExportFactory and SatisfyImportsOnce, but I'm not satisfied with it, I need just GetExportedValues

Comment: I'm in contact with one of the guys developing MEF for metro style apps. He told me, that SatisfyImportsOnce is currently the only way to compose items. He asked me, what specific scenarios I have in mind which are not supported by SatisfyImportOnce:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winappswithcsharp/thread/6aff302d-867a-4921-86ae-b8088c47560f

I found a tiny alternative to MEF for the time being:
http://metroioc.codeplex.com/

Hope it also can help you.

Comment: I don't want to use other frameworks as I want to share some code between projects. and as soon I'm already using MEF in the source project I want to continue to use it. My needs aren't too big, so I prefer to add missing functionality. I'll add my current solution as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I already wrote in the comment, I don't really like this approach, but it is the best what I have up to this moment:

```
public class CompositionContainer
{
    private readonly CompositionService _service;

    public CompositionContainer(CompositionService service)
    {
        _service = service;
    }

    public T GetExportedValue<T>()
    {
        var factoryProvider = new FactoryProvider<T>();
        _service.SatisfyImportsOnce(factoryProvider);
        return factoryProvider.Factory.CreateExport().Value;
    }

    private class FactoryProvider<T>
    {
        [Import]
        public ExportFactory<T> Factory;
    }
}
```

and the simple use-case might be this one:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var catalog = new ApplicationCatalog();
        var container = new CompositionContainer(catalog.CreateCompositionService());
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            var dude = container.GetExportedValue<IDude>();
            Console.WriteLine(dude.Say());
        }
    }
    public interface IDude
    {
        string Say();
    }

    [Export(typeof(IDude))]
    public class Eminem : IDude
    {
        private static int _instanceNo;
        private readonly string _phrase;

        public Eminem()
        {
            _instanceNo++;
            _phrase = string.Join(" ", Enumerable.Range(0, _instanceNo)
                .Select(_ => "yo!"));
        }

        public string Say()
        {
            return _phrase;
        }
    }
}
```

I don't care about performance at this moment, but I guess I'll add caching of factory providers or factories later

Comment: It is not a bad approach! Just a pitty that we have to write such code ourself :( Thanks dude.

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing you have discovered the `System.CompononentModel.Composition` and `System.CompononentModel.Composition.Hosting` namespaces.

Let me give you a simple example here (and see if you are missing anything).

First of all you need a component to inject:

```
public interface IMefTest
{
   string Message {get;}
}

[Export(typeof(IMefTest))]
public class MefTest: IMefTest
{
   public string Message {get { return "Hello World"; }}
}
```

Next you need to set up the `CompositionService` (this is similar to a container, but not exactly). We want to set this up somewhere that it can be commonly talked to since this will be where you call to satisfy imports (more on that in code snippet after this one).

I stuck this in the App.xaml.cs in my sample project:

```
static System.ComponentModel.Composition.ICompositionService _compositionService = null;
public static System.ComponentModel.Composition.ICompositionService CompositionService
{
    get
    {
        if (_compositionService == null)
            ((App)App.Current).loadCompositionService();
         return _compositionService;
    }
}

private void loadCompositionService()
{
    // Create a catalog where MEF will search for exported parts to plugin
    var catalog = new System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting.AssemblyCatalog(GetType().GetTypeInfo().Assembly);
    _compositionService = catalog.CreateCompositionService();
}
```

Just a little info on this. We have set up an assembly catalog which means that MEF will interrogate just this Assembly looking for types that are exported. There are other types of catalogs and I believe you should be able to combine 2 or more catalogs together.

Ok, in my page (BTW, I built this into the C# HelloWorld Example from the Getting Started docs on MSDN).

To get an instance of one of the parts in the catalog you simple need to add a property to the class you want to get and add an imports attribute (there are also ways to have it specify arguments on your constructor, but I'm trying to stay simple)

```
[Import]
public IMefTest Tester { get; set; }
```

In this example, you'll need to call the composition service's SatisfyImportsOnce method on this class. I did this in the constructor and I did it like this:

```
if(App.CompositionService != null)
  App.CompositionService.SatisfyImportsOnce(this);
```

(The check to make sure that the service exists is overkill on my part.. it should exist).
After that step you can actually use the `Tester.Message` property within your class. There are a lot more options within MEF. I hope this helps you out (and if it does you mark me as the answer as I took valuable time from billing clients to do this for you )

Also, I know you wanted to simply call a container and have it give you back an instance of some type. It is possible to do this with the other forms of MEF, so I imagine it should be able to be done with WinRT, but I am honestly unsure at this time).

Comment: Hello DevTheo, this I figured out already, unfortunately it is not exactly what I'm searching. The container allowed to get a specific export value, without to satisfy any imports: container.GetExportedValue<IServiceLocator>(); I'm searching an equivalent function on the Metro MEF.

Comment: Sorry I didn't nail it for you... I couldn't quite find exactly what you wanted (and like I said needed to get back to customers work <grin/>)..

If I get a chance I will look a little further.. I have another idea, but need to experiment with something before I say I have it..

Comment: I don't expect that you nail it for me ;) I already have an idea how I can do it, but I haven't enought time yet ^^ But I don't think that it can be done without some custom code.