# Standard Architecture for Building Metro apps

Tags: c#-4.0, architecture, windows-8, windows-runtime, microsoft-metro

I am new to Metro apps...and have been developing on WPF(MVVM) for some time...

I also saw that WPF like `Binding` Engine is also there with Metro apps ..

So here i ask a few question ..

**What is a suitable architecture to develop a maintainable Meto app.**

Is it
1) MVC
2) MVVM

**Are there any framework that could be used to develop the same using the above Architectures.**

**Can MEF be used with mero apps** (I dont think so but still need to confirm).

Comment: It looks like you can use MEF in WinRT - although there are limitations: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9522783/how-to-get-exported-values-mef-in-metro-style-apps

Comment: @Krishna Thanks for the link... although its too bad MEF's out of the box functionality is missing in Metro apps :( .

Answer (score 3):

MVVM is a totally fine choice and a MVVM Light for WinRT is available. In regard to MEF there is a SO question that elaborates on this ( [How to load/import dll with MEF out of metro app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9669097/how-to-load-import-dll-with-mef-out-of-metro-app) )

**Edit:**

MVVM Light Download for Windows 8 http://mvvmlight.codeplex.com/releases/view/88894

Announcement: http://blog.galasoft.ch/archive/2012/06/03/mvvmlight-v4-for-windows-8-rp-is-available.aspx